# How to pass an array with key into view using Template Parser in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Guys I want to pass my variable `$data` with a key, something like this
`$data['student']` using Template parser library of CI. If I pass it
with a key `$data['student']` it doesn't work,

Now the problem is if
`$data['any_key'] = 'Any value';` is defined before `$data` code 
( given below in controller ) it is replaced by it. So this means i will have
to define `$data = array()` on the first line and then i can define any key
i.e `data['any_value']='xyz'` wont get replaced.

**This is my Controller**

```
$result = $this->test->view_all('student',['STUD_Gender'=>'Male']);

$data['key'] = 'xyz'; //will get replaced

$data = array(
        'blog_title'   => 'School',
        'blog_heading' => 'Students',
        'blog_entries' => $result
        );

$data['key'] = 'xyz'; //wont get replaced

$this->parser->parse('test/header',$data);      
$this->parser->parse('test/index',$data);
$this->load->view('test/footer');
```

**This is my View**

```
<p>{blog_title}</p>
   <h1>{blog_heading}</h1>
        {blog_entries}
                <h3>{STUD_NAME}</h3>
                <p>{STUD_EMAIL}</p>
                <p>{STUD_GENDER}</p>
                <p>{STUD_PHONE}</p>                                
        {/blog_entries}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Use `$data` like this :*

```
// add key like this 
$data['student'] = 'xyz'; 

$data['blog_title'] = 'School'; 
$data['blog_heading'] = 'Students';

$result = $this->test->view_all('student',['STUD_Gender'=>'Male']);
$data['blog_entries'] = $result; 

$this->parser->parse('test/header',$data);      
$this->parser->parse('test/index',$data);
$this->load->view('test/footer');
```

*Your view should be like this :*

```
// use key in view like this
<p>{student}</p>
<p>{blog_title}</p>
<h1>{blog_heading}</h1>
{blog_entries}
  <h3>{STUD_NAME}</h3>
  <p>{STUD_EMAIL}</p>
  <p>{STUD_GENDER}</p>
  <p>{STUD_PHONE}</p>                                
{/blog_entries}
```

Comment: pleasure is mine, happy coding